# How do you git fetch all repos in a folder?

Tags: macos, script, git

I keep all the repositories I work on in a folder on my machine `~/Code`, and I want a script to execute `git fetch && git status` against each of the repos in that folder.

I imagine that, if it’s possible, it might look something like this pseudocode:

```sh
cd ~/Code
    && for each subfolder in ~/Documents (git fetch && git status)
    && echo "here’s the repos with updated remotes:\n"
    && echo reportReposWithRemoteChanges
```

I tried [Tower](https://git-tower.com) which does not appear to offer this. I also tried [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com), which provides irregular support for highlighting *some* local repositories whose remotes have updates.

Answer (score 3):

Given your inclination towards GUI: See [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/). Custom commands: https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/custom_commands

Also, [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com). It has the ability to add scripts as custom functions.

One can combine `find . -type d -iname ".git" -exec echo {} \;` and replace `echo` command with  a script with the following contents:
This takes care of submodules also.

```
cd "$1"
# The $1 is the `project/.git`, so cd into parent directory.
cd ..
# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommitted-changes 
# but  `git fetch` would also exit if there are any changes. 
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    echo "no changes"
else
    echo "changes"
    exit
fi

if [[ -z $(git status -s) ]]
then
    echo "no changes1"
else
    echo "changes1"
    exit
fi

git fetch && git status
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a folder structure like the following:

```
"~/Code"
├── "README.md"
├── "file-0.txt"
├── "repo-1"
│   ├── ".git"
│   ├── ".gitignore"
│   ├── "README.md"
│   ├── "file-1.txt"
│   └── "file-2.txt"
├── "repo-2"
│   ├── ".git"
│   ├── ".gitignore"
│   ├── "file-3.txt"
│   └── "file-4.txt"
└── "repo-3"
    ├── ".git"
    └── "file-5.txt"
```

You could use the following Bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd "$HOME/Code"

for repo in */; do
    echo "$repo:"
    cd "$repo"
    git fetch
    git status
    cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
fd .git -H -t d -x git --git-dir={} fetch \; -x git --git-dir={} --work-tree {}/.. status
```

This will execute on every git repo under the current directory,
regardless of the depth.

In fact,

```bash
fd .git -H -t d
```

finds all the `.git` folders under the current directory.